# Analize and match comments with words via a for loop function

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i want to analize the first already inserted comment too, and match those 4 words with the comment(if they match, the comment will be bordered with blue line). The problem is, when i want to match them something is going wrong. the function is ignoring the first comment and shows error with inpuText.textContent. When i add a new comment and i want to match that new comment with a new inserted word that works fine. The final process is: To take all the words(already existed, or input words), all the comments and match them, independently of numbers of comments and words.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}


function createparagraph() {
  var commentdiv = document.createElement("div");
  commentdiv.id = "comment";
  commentdiv.className = "col-md-12 bordered commentdiv"
  var imagediv = document.createElement("div");
  imagediv.id = "imagediv";
  imagediv.className = "col-md-2 bordered logo";
  var logoimg = document.createElement("img");
  logoimg.id = "logoimage";
  logoimg.setAttribute("src", "logo.jpg");
  var paragraphdiv = document.createElement("div");
  paragraphdiv.id = "paragraphdiv"
  paragraphdiv.className = "col-md-10 para bordered paragraphdiv";
  var inputtext = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
  var createp = document.createElement("P");
  createp.className = "commentpgraph";
  createp.id = "commentparagraph";
  var it = document.createTextNode(inputtext);
  var area = document.getElementById("pgraf");
  createp.appendChild(it);
  commentdiv.appendChild(imagediv);
  commentdiv.appendChild(paragraphdiv);
  paragraphdiv.appendChild(createp);
  imagediv.appendChild(logoimg);
  document.getElementById("commentsec").appendChild(commentdiv);
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("commentdiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].setAttribute("id", "comment" + i);
  }
  var pgraph = document.getElementsByClassName("commentpgraph");
  for (var i = 0; i < pgraph.length; i++) {
    pgraph[i].setAttribute("id", "commentparagraph" + i);
  }
  var paragraphdiv = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraphdiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphdiv.length; i++) {
    paragraphdiv[i].setAttribute("id", "paragraphdiv" + i);
  }
  myFunction();

}

function listFunction() {
  document.getElementById("listForm").reset();
}

function creatediv() {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.id = "blacklisttab" + i;
  newdiv.className = "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab";
  var innerdiv = document.createElement("div");
  innerdiv.id = "torles";
  innerdiv.className = "col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment";
  var newspan = document.createElement("span");
  newspan.id = "closebutn";
  newspan.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  };
  newspan.innerHTML = "x";
  var textdiv = document.createElement("div");
  textdiv.id = "blacklistitem";
  textdiv.className = "blacklistitem";
  var inputtext = document.getElementById("littletext").value;
  var createp = document.createElement("P");
  createp.className = "blacklistitempgraph";
  createp.id = "blacklistitempgraph";
  var it = document.createTextNode(inputtext);
  var area = document.getElementById("blacklistitem");
  newdiv.appendChild(innerdiv);
  innerdiv.appendChild(newspan);
  innerdiv.appendChild(textdiv);
  createp.appendChild(it);
  textdiv.appendChild(createp);
  document.getElementById("blacklist").appendChild(newdiv);
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("blacklisttab");
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("blacklistitem")
  var blacklistitempgraph = document.getElementsByClassName("blacklistitempgraph");
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].setAttribute("id", "blacklisttab" + i);
    items[i].setAttribute("id", "blacklistitem" + i);
    blacklistitempgraph[i].setAttribute("id", "blacklistitempgraph" + i);
  }
  listFunction();

  bordering1();

}

function bordering1() {
  var blitems = document.getElementsByClassName("blacklisttab");
  for (var i = 0; i < blitems.length; i++) {
    var text = document.getElementById("blacklistitempgraph" + i).textContent;
  };
  var n = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraphdiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("commentparagraph" + i);
    var innerHTML = inputText.textContent;
    var index = n[i].innerHTML.indexOf(text);
    if (index > 0) {
      n[i].setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid blue;");

    }
  }
};
```

```css
.abutton {
  padding: 10px;
}

.para {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.textarea {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.fragment {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  height: 20px;
  border: px solid blue;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#close {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.closebtn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#textarea {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  background: url(bc.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.textplace {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#littletext {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  background: url(bc.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
}

#closebutn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  border-style: solid;
}

#commentsec {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 bordered blacklist listform">
  <div class="col-md-12 bordered blacklist" id="blacklist">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="listtab">
      <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
        <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
          <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph">DNFB</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="listtab">
      <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
        <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
          <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph">HIM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="listtab">
      <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
        <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
          <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph">CFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="listtab">
      <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
        <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
          <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph">Reduce</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 bordered">
    <form id="listForm">
      <textarea name="littletext" id="littletext" rows="1" style="width: 105%;"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 bordered">
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="creatediv()">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 bordered bottom">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bordered commentsec" id="commentsec">
    <div class="col-md-12 bordered commentdiv" id="comment">

      <div class="col-md-10 para bordered paragraphdiv" id="paragraphdiv">
        <p class="commentpgraph" id="commentparagraph">Significantly Reduce Costs and Improve Quality with an Experienced, Professional Global Coding Solution. Health Information Management (HIM) Directors and CFOs are seeking innovative ways to reduce expenses, maintain DNFB goals, and increase overall
          coder quality.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bordered textarea">
    <form id="myForm">
      <textarea id="textarea" style="width: 100%;" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8 bordered abutton">
    <center><input type="Submit" id="button1" value="Submit" onclick="createparagraph();"></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 forms listForm and myForm? Cannot find either form in your html source (only in your JavaScript)..

Comment: To reset those 2 inputs

Comment: The submit buttons need to be inside form tag..